# "Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time"

Tags: swift

I am a beginner developer and I am getting this error

> Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time.

```swift
var body: some View {
ZStack {
    ScrollView {
        VStack {
            Text("Welcome \(CloudkitUserAuth().vm.userName)") <- (Error here)
            Image("H&I Logo")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 115, height: 115)
                .padding()
        }

struct CloudkitUserAuth: View {

@StateObject var vm = CLoudKitUserAuthViewModel()
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("IS SIGNED IN: \(vm.isSignedInToiCloud.description.uppercased())")
        Text(vm.error)
        Text("Permission: \(vm.permissionStatus.description.uppercased())")
        Text("Welcome \(vm.userName)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you do the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/

Comment: In short, right now, you're creating a `View` inside of a `String` and then trying to reach inside of that view and access a `@StateObject` property on it. There are a couple of issues with this including: 1) Creating a `View` inside a `String` 2) Trying to reach inside a `View` to access its properties. You could, for example, make the `@StateObject` owned by a common parent of both of the Views you've shown. I second the recommendation to check out some SwiftUI tutorials -- you'll get more comfortable with the paradigms there.

Answer (score 3):

I second the comment saying you should look at apple's intro tutorial on SwiftUI, but here's a quick working example of your code to hopefully help out as well.

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // these @Published vars were put here to most-simply demonstrate 
    // ownership/state-based  observed updates. You should refactor so 
    // user values (like userName) are separate from auth-specific data,
    // and mutable values (like permissionStatus) are owned by the 
    // view-model that's observed by the view they're updated in
    @Published private var isSignedInToiCloud = false
    @Published private var error = ""
    @Published private var permissionStatus = false
    @Published private(set) var userName = "willy"

    var authViewModel: CLoudKitUserAuthViewModel {
        .init(
            isSignedInToiCloud: isSignedInToiCloud,
            error: error,
            permissionStatus: permissionStatus,
            userName: userName
        )
    }
}

struct CLoudKitUserAuthViewModel {
    let isSignedInToiCloud: Bool
    let error: String
    let permissionStatus: Bool
    let userName: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ContentViewModel() // observed view model owned by parent view

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Text("Welcome \(vm.userName)") // access userName directly
                    CloudkitUserAuthDetail(vm: vm.authViewModel) // create auth detail using computed view-model
                    Image("H&I Logo")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 115, height: 115)
                        .padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CloudkitUserAuthDetail: View {
    let vm: CLoudKitUserAuthViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("IS SIGNED IN: \(vm.isSignedInToiCloud.description.uppercased())")
            Text(vm.error)
            Text("Permission: \(vm.permissionStatus.description.uppercased())")
            Text("Welcome \(vm.userName)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great example, and thank you for spending some time to provide a working example of the issue at hand.  It helped me because sometimes it is good to see a real example even if you have read Apple's tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I needed to switch stateObject into observedObject